# axios isURLSameOrigin undefined

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to pass `url` variable to axios call:

```
let timer;
 document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        const url = "/register-item/categories";
             filter.filterSubmit(selectTypeId, url);
        }, 500);
    });

 filterSubmit(selectTypeId, url) {
   http({
       method: 'post',
       url: url,
       data: {
           item_type_id: selectTypeId,
       }
     })
}
```

but I get this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of isURLSameOrigin.js undefined (reading 'protocol')`.
And when I do it like this:

```
http({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/register-item/categories'
    })
```

Everything works fine.

Comment: Do you call `.protocol` anywhere?

Comment: It is hard to draw conclusion of what could be the error. You might need to share more code or even better try to reproduce it on ts playground at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGcHsFsFNQMaQCayA

Comment: Are you sure the variable `url` is what you think it is? Can you place a `console.log(url)` just before your `http(...)` call (inside `filterSubmit`)? Does it log the URL you expect it to log?

Comment: I fixed it, I found that that I wasnt passing variable to function at one place in code. Sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
filterSubmit(url) {
 http({
       method: 'post',
       url,
     })
}
```

Comment: Did not change anything

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Edited code with what I have

Comment: It's not enough. Show all of your code?

Comment: I fixed it, I found that that I wasnt passing variable to function at one place in code.